# One time key for authentication

Tags: c#, validation, api, cryptography

In a recent project I was to create a web service that would be consumed by another application. One of the requirements was to have a key in the service that authenticated the request as valid. But this key must never be the same and the key should be invalid soon after its use.

This is the code I wrote to that purpose.

```
public static bool isKeyValid(long testKey)
{
    var k = GetKey();

    var allowedVariance = 0.00000000004;
    var variance = k * allowedVariance;

    return (k + variance >= testKey && k - variance <= testKey);
}

public static long GetKey()
{
    var i = (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks * 5;
    var d = (long)Math.Sqrt(Math.Ceiling(400 - (DateTime.UtcNow.Day * Math.PI)));
    var k = (long)((Math.Round((Math.Sqrt(i) * Math.Pow(Math.PI + d, 3)) * Math.E - d)) * d) + DateTime.UtcNow.Minute;
    return k;
}
```

The point being that the caller generates a key and the receiver generates its own and then compares these two and says everything is ok if the difference is within a given variance.

Note that nothing in the message is really secret and this is just a simple check so that the request is probably from a valid source.

I have two questions for this.

1. How could I have done this better in terms of existing encryption
   libraries (in .Net) or using other things such as certificates. This must work     cross platform (Windows, iOS, and Android devices)
2. How can the given code be modified or improved to make it better for
   the intended purpose?

Comment: How did you come up with the key calculation? Have you made this up or does this algorithm have a name?

Comment: I made it up. Purpose being for it is to increase rapidly during the day. And make a jump in numbers every night.

Comment: I think you might get more feedback about your algorithm on the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Is the key type required to be long?

Comment: In my algorithm the generated number is larger than an int, so yes it is. You could rewrite it to produce smaller numbers if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

General coding style

- avoid using var because it obscures the datatypes.
- use meaningful variable names.
- when comparing ranges, put the thing being tested in the middle and keep both comparison operators the same.
- always use the same value for UtcNow, because the clock is ticking.
- document every function you write (1 or 2 lines of comments above each function)

Example:

```
// Returns true if this key value came from GetKey(), false otherwise.
public static bool IsKeyValid(long testKey)
{
    long k = GetKey();

    double allowedVariance = 0.00000000004;   // say what this is ...

    // You use of 'var' obscured the differing datatypes: k and testKey are long.
    double variance = k * allowedVariance;    

    return (k - variance <= testKey && testKey <= k + variance);
}

// Returns a key based on the current time.
public static long GetKey()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Explanation is called for here...
    long i = now.Ticks * 5;
    long d = (long)Math.Sqrt(Math.Ceiling(400 - (now.Day * Math.PI)));
    long k = (long)((Math.Round((Math.Sqrt(i) * Math.Pow(Math.PI + d, 3)) * Math.E - d)) * d) + now.Minute;

    return k;
}
```

I know nothing about encryption so cannot say whether there are built-in .NET functions which perform the same task, but there probably are.

Comment: _avoid using var because it obscures the datatypes_ `var` everywhere! ;-)

Comment: The *one* nice thing about var is it helps you find accidental implicit type conversions. `double value = 1.0f;` won't tell you that you're implicitly converting a `float` to a `double`, but if you do `var value = 1.0f;` and inspect the type you can *see* that it's a `float` much more easily.

Comment: Why would you care that you are implicitly converting a *compile-time constant* `float` to a `double`? @ebrown

Comment: @CodyGray That's an example, ignore the compile-time issue. Consider: `double result = SomeMethodReturnsFloat();` vs `var result = SomeMethodReturnsFloat();`.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better example. Still, it's a widening conversion, so it's guaranteed to be safe. I remain unconvinced that this is something I need to be concerned about. @ebrown

Comment: @CodyGray That's fine, I'm not going to spend time trying to convince you. It's a preference, I **hate** hidden implicit conversions in my code, they come with interesting costs associated to them.